# youtube-dl "yt-dlp" How to download audios that have subtitles and ignore everything else

Tags: youtube, youtube-dl

I've tried using the following command to filter out audios that have subtitles and ignore the ones without.

However, it still downloads videos that don't have subtitles. Any idea why?

```
yt-dlp https://www.youtube.com/c/FriderikuszPodcast/videos --match-filter subtitles --min-sleep-interval 4 --max-sleep-interval 6 --sub-langs all,-live_chat --audio-multistreams --extract-audio --audio-format wav -o "%(title)s.%(ext)s" --restrict-filenames
```